# Trying to get a StatusBar in app that could be accessible from various pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, statusbar

I have implemented two pages with navigation. Here is how my MainWindow and two pages are declared.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sb="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame x:Name="frame"  Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my Page1

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="This is Page 1" FontSize="20" />
        <Button Content="Next"  Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is Page2

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="This is Page 2" FontSize="20" />
        <Button Content="Exit"  Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In the code behind of MainWindow constructor, I navigate to Page1.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.frame.Navigate(new Page1());
        }
```

When I run the application, I get to see Page1. Life is good so far. I now need to bring a StatusBar where text will be updated from Page1 and Page2. I started with following interface.

```
public interface ISBView
    {
        void UpdateMessage(string message);
    }
```

I then created a user control that implements this interface with following code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyStatusBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="statusMessage" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

public partial class MyStatusBar : UserControl, ISBView
    {
        public MyStatusBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void UpdateMessage(string message)
        {
            this.statusMessage.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

I then used this user control in the MainWindow as follows.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sb="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Frame x:Name="frame"  Grid.Row="0" />
        <StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.Row="1" >
            <StatusBarItem>
                <sb:MyStatusBar x:Name="myStatusBar" Content="Hi there!!!"  />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the constructor of MainWindow is changed to:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.frame.Navigate(new Page1(this.myStatusBar));
        }
```

Whereas Page1 class looks like as follows.

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        private ISBView statusBar;
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Page1(ISBView sb):base() 
        {
            this.statusBar = sb;
            sb.UpdateMessage("now on page1");
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Page2());
        }
    }
```

Problem is now when I run application, Page1 is not shown at all. I  just get a blank page without any error. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the constructor of your Page. When you call your base constructor , the InitializeComponent() will not call and UI cannot render. So you should be calling 'this' constructor to  execute both your logic and InitializationComponent().

```
    public Page1(ISBView sb) : this() 
    {
        this.statusBar = sb;
        sb.UpdateMessage("now on page1");
    }
```